# How to make a child div with css at least as tall as its parent div with unknown height

Tags: css

If the height of the menu div smaller than it's parent div, it should expand to the height of the parent, which does not have a known height. This part is like the equal column high problem.

But if the menu div is larger than the parent's div it should **neither shrink** to the parent's size **nor enlarge the parent's div**.

*The (text) content coming in the following div should flow nicely around the menu div, but that seems not to be complicate.*

Is that possible with just css or do I need js? With js it it won't be that difficult but I would like to have a css only solution.

[image: Layout]

```css
.main-top {
  position: relative;
}
.navigation {
width: 200px;
background-color: #999;
margin-right: 10px;
float: left;
}
.page-title,
figure {
margin-left: 210px;
}
figure {
color: #ddd;
}
.menu-2 {
/* set display: block; to simulate more content here*/
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-top">
  <header class="article">
    <section class="navigation">
      <h2 class="pane-title">Menu</h2>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li>
          <a href="#">1. Lorem ipsum aeque oratio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2. Postulant vim in</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3. Ne zzril qualisque sadipscing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">4. Eu per ubique eligendi quaerendum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">5. Lorem ipsum aeque oratio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">6. Postulant vim in</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">.....</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">X. Eu per ubique eligendi quaerendum</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
            <ul class="menu-2">
        <li>
          <a href="#">1. Lorem ipsum aeque oratio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">2. Postulant vim in</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">3. Ne zzril qualisque sadipscing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">4. Eu per ubique eligendi quaerendum</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">5. Lorem ipsum aeque oratio</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">6. Postulant vim in</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">.....</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">X. Eu per ubique eligendi quaerendum</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="page-title">
      <h1>An soluta quidam cum duo dolor dissentias, ne sea volutpat theophrastus</h1>
    </div>
    <figure class="pane-panels-mini">
      <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pv8d.png" width="250" height="375" alt="Layout" title="I hope it works like that" />
      <figcaption class="">
        Lorem ipsum aeque oratio postulant vim in. Ne zzril qualisque sadipscing pri, eu per ubique eligendi quaerendum. An soluta quidam cum. No duo dolor dissentias, ne sea volutpat theophrastus, illum laoreet nonummy ius ne.
      </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </header>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut pellentesque leo vitae accumsan egestas. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque volutpat, diam ac rutrum dapibus, sapien sapien lobortis est, nec tincidunt elit risus
    et massa. Sed ultrices posuere nunc non mollis.</p>
  <p>Maecenas dictum interdum odio, eu consequat enim porta eget. Ut fringilla elit a arcu euismod, vel accumsan mauris convallis. Donec nec nunc tempor, imperdiet odio vel, dignissim urna.</p>
  <p>Nullam volutpat facilisis leo eleifend molestie. Nunc dolor magna, molestie nec sollicitudin vel, dignissim in eros. Morbi imperdiet neque vitae magna laoreet, ut aliquet urna pellentesque. Phasellus euismod libero mollis erat feugiat, sed consectetur
    nunc facilisis.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide working snippet code.

Comment: @Paulie_D your assumptions about my attempts are not correct, the note from ankita said it all, anyway thanks for commenting. I now added a code snippet with html and css. It's not as minimal as it might be, I left some stuff to show that there are more tags that might be helpful for moving the blocks around with negative margins etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try floating your menu element to the left ie `<div style="float: right;">` and giving it fixed dimensions. Content should wrap just fine without changing the dimensions of your menu element.

```css
ul {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
</ul>

<h1>Title element</h1>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident pariatur repellat aspernatur alias unde dolore culpa, quae eligendi veritatis quidem quam, cupiditate minus reprehenderit deserunt nisi laborum. Distinctio, consequatur at?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident pariatur repellat aspernatur alias unde dolore culpa, quae eligendi veritatis quidem quam, cupiditate minus reprehenderit deserunt nisi laborum. Distinctio, consequatur at?</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident pariatur repellat aspernatur alias unde dolore culpa, quae eligendi veritatis quidem quam, cupiditate minus reprehenderit deserunt nisi laborum. Distinctio, consequatur at?</p>
```

Comment: Thank you Danny, this is my actual behavior but that way the black menu div won't be as tall as the parent div – except the parent div won't be less than 200px.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this.

Important bits are `position:absolute` and `min-height:100%`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 120px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    
    <div class="menu">menu</div>
    
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    content content<br>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Rauli for taking the time to answer my question. I implemented your solution and it works very well for the described case. There is one more detail I didn't explain carefully enough: Below the parent content there will be another div that. It's content should float around the menu div. I improved the drawing by adding the red content div.